# Filtering first item in List<Contract> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `var contracts = new List<Contract>();` which is the master list of all contracts written in a particular time frame. The contract object looks like this:

```
public class Contract
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public DateTime ContractDate { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The master list may or may not contain multiple contracts with the same company, so not all `CompanyId`'s may be unique.

My task is to produce:

1. All "first" contracts which means if there's only one contract with a company, it would go into my output. If there are multiple contracts with the same company, then I'd pick the one with the smallest/oldest `ContractDate`
2. I also need to produce a list that's the opposite of the first one which means, I need to include in my output all the second, third, etc. contracts. If there's only one contract with a company, I'd include that in my output but if I have multiple contracts with a company, I would skip the first one and include the rest in my output.

I can do this using a `foreach` loop but wanted to see how I could produce the same results using `LINQ`.

Comment: Share that code in which you can do it with `foreach` loop as to have some kind of minimal reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one I believe this will do

```
contracts
    .GroupBy(c => c.CompanyId)
    .Select(c => c.OrderBy(o => o.ContractDate).First());
```

And for the second one:

```
contracts
    .GroupBy(c => c.CompanyId)
    .Select(c => c.OrderBy(o => o.ContractDate).Skip(c.Count() == 1 ? 0 : 1))
    .SelectMany(c => c)
```

Comment: Better than mine, give the devil his due, +1

Comment: The only improvement is to add `.ToList()` at the end so that I get a list of contracts. Other than that, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Until now, I've done first one albeit not easy as expected as.

```
var results =
                from kvp in list
                group kvp by kvp.CompanyId into g
                select new
                {
                    Group = g,
                    Max = g.Max(kvp => kvp.ContractDate),
                } into ag
                from x in ag.Group
                where x.ContractDate == ag.Max
                select new
                {
                    CompanyId = x.CompanyId,
                    Amount = x.Amount,
                    ContractDate = ag.Max,
                    CompanyName = x.CompanyName
                };
```

To test,

```
public static void Main()
{
    var c1 = new Contract { Id = 1, CompanyId = 1000, CompanyName = "ABC", Amount = 1337, ContractDate = new DateTime(2000, 12, 30)};
    var c2 = new Contract { Id = 2, CompanyId = 1001, CompanyName = "XYZ", Amount = 97, ContractDate = new DateTime(2001, 12, 30)};
    var c3 = new Contract { Id = 3, CompanyId = 2222, CompanyName = "iQuest", Amount = -999, ContractDate = new DateTime(1994, 1, 1)};
    var c4 = new Contract { Id = 4, CompanyId = 2222, CompanyName = "iQuest", Amount = -999, ContractDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)};

    var list = new List<Contract> { c1, c2, c3, c4 };

    var results =
    from kvp in list
    group kvp by kvp.CompanyId into g
    select new
    {
      Group = g,
      Max = g.Max(kvp => kvp.ContractDate),
    } into ag
    from x in ag.Group
    where x.ContractDate == ag.Max
    select new
    {
      CompanyId = x.CompanyId,
      Amount = x.Amount,
      ContractDate = ag.Max,
      CompanyName = x.CompanyName
    };
}

// Define other methods, classes and namespaces here
public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ContractDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the asker requests you to write their code for them. This encourages laziness and poor quality questions.

Comment: @IanKemp I know. I just regard the question as a practice to improve my linq skill.